# retrieve specific value from sql table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have divided login to 2 parts one for admin and one for user,
they`re differentiated through TypeID field which has values 1 and 2

I want to make function that check the TypeID to decide the response redirect page

I got this so far

```
Public Shared Function CheckUser(ByVal usename As String) As Int32
    Const sql = "SELECT TypeID FROM Registration where usename = @UserName"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RegconnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeID", usename)
            con.Open()
            Dim x As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar
            Return x
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

the input for this function will be the text coming from textUserName.text

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but i think you're trying to set the @UserName parameter - while actually adding the @TypeID, which would be your return.

I think the 5th line should actually look like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", usename)
```

Hope it works for you.